# Is what seems to be a LiveBindings quirk still present in recent Delphi versions, e.g. Rio?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Below is a minimal FMX LiveBindings project written & compiled with Delphi Seattle
which (I hope!) shows a long-standing issue with LiveBindings which goes back to
the first time I attempted to use them in the XE4 era.

I've included the code and a .DFM extract below for the avoidance of any doubt as
to how things are set up.

In Seattle, when I run the app, what I see in the StringGrid is the row with ID = 1
followed by two copies of row ID 3, with no ID 2.

My question is, assuming your results in Seattle if you have it don't contradict
mine, is this quirk still present in more recent Delphi versions in particular Rio?

While you have the app running, there is another quirk which seems easily provoked:

- Double-click the Name cell of the first row so that the StringGrid goes into
  editing mode.
- Press the <kbd>Down</kbd> key.

When I do that, I get the CPU window up and

```
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project BindingsQuirk2.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x095b9633: write of address 0x00000001'.
---------------------------
Break   Continue   Help
---------------------------
```

Code

```
type
  TLBForm = class(TForm)
    ADataSet: TSimpleDataSet;
    ADataSetID: TIntegerField;
    ADataSetName: TStringField;
    BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB;
    StringGrid1: TStringGrid;
    BindingsList1: TBindingsList;
    NavigatorBindSourceDB1: TBindNavigator;
    LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB1: TLinkGridToDataSource;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ADataSetNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
  private
    NextID : Integer;
    ALinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB1: TLinkGridToDataSource;
  end;

  [...]

procedure TLBForm.ADataSetNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Inc(NextID);
  ADataSetID.AsInteger := NextID;
  ADataSetName.AsString := 'RowID' + IntToStr(NextID);
end;

procedure TLBForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  ADataSet.IndexFieldNames := 'ID';
  ADataSet.OnNewRecord := ADataSetNewRecord;

  ADataSet.CreateDataSet;

  for i := 1 to 3 do begin
    ADataSet.Insert;
    ADataSet.Post;
  end;

  ADataSet.First;

end;
```

DFM extract

```
object LBForm: TLBForm
  object StringGrid1: TStringGrid
    CanFocus = True
    ClipChildren = True
    Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 16.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 26
    Viewport.Width = 180.000000000000000000
    Viewport.Height = 75.000000000000000000
  end
  object NavigatorBindSourceDB1: TBindNavigator
    Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 128.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 240.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 25.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 31
    DataSource = BindSourceDB1
    xRadius = 4.000000000000000000
    yRadius = 4.000000000000000000
  end
  object ADataSet: TSimpleDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    DataSet.MaxBlobSize = -1
    DataSet.Params = <>
    Params = <>
    OnNewRecord = ADataSetNewRecord
    object ADataSetID: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'ID'
    end
    object ADataSetName: TStringField
      FieldName = 'Name'
      Size = 30
    end
  end
  object BindSourceDB1: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = ADataSet
    ScopeMappings = <>
  end
  object BindingsList1: TBindingsList
    Methods = <>
    OutputConverters = <>
    object LinkGridToDataSourceBindSourceDB1: TLinkGridToDataSource
      DataSource = BindSourceDB1
      GridControl = StringGrid1
      Columns = <>
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: No exception triggered here with 10.3.3 but I do see duplicated new rows visually after adding some.

Comment: Final two rows are visually the same even when the actual data is fine.  Odd.

Comment: @Brian:  Thanks for the info and sorry for the slow reply.